# For or While with Javascript and Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Is this possible with Firebase and Javascript?
I have a realtime Database which looks like this:
[image: P1]

Now I want to get access to this database and copy these two parent string into an array.
After that I want a for or while loop where this function below gets executed but one time with the first string and the second time with the second string.

This is the code:

```
var ref = db.ref('/user/' + >>Place String<< + '/notification/'+ subMessageID + '/subMessageID/').set(subMessageID);
```

The result should be the same as if I would have typed this:

```
var ref = db.ref('/user/' + 'PpRWBqHFYlg78vSeutNOAPMG3wv1' + '/notification/'+ subMessageID + '/subMessageID/').set(subMessageID);
var ref = db.ref('/user/' + 'hSzkimAs1fWgNke9stnQnf7cNyi2' + '/notification/'+ subMessageID + '/subMessageID/').set(subMessageID);
```

The path till notification is known. But I don't know how many strings are stored in notification. So it needs to get all of them.

I watched [this tutorial here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp) with while and for loops but they work with arrays.

Updated code:
What If I have to add multiple things to my database like this instead of only one line like above?

```
var ref = db.ref('/user/' + >>Place String<< + '/notification/'+ subMessageID + '/subMessageID/').set(subMessageID);
 var ref = db.ref('/user/' + >>Place String<< + '/notification/'+ subMessageID + '/userTime/').set(userTime);
 var ref = db.ref('/user/' + >>Place String<< + '/notification/'+ subMessageID + '/userName/').set(nameUser);
```

Suggested code:

```
 function checkpath() {
            var db = admin.database();
            var ref =  db.ref('placeID/here:pds:place:276u0wuu-237aa2acb3b9ce0/-ND4CBIpq7Pds/notification');
            ref.get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
              if (snapshot.exists()) {
                console.log("snapshot existiert und daten wurden auf user eingetragen");

                const keyArray = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
                // We pass an Array of Promises to Promise.all(), see the doc (link below)
                return Promise.all(keyArray.map(k => db.ref('/user/' + k + '/notification/' + subMessageID + '/subMessageID/').set(subMessageID), db.ref('/user/' + k + '/notification/' + subMessageID + '/userTime/').set(userTime)));
              } else {
                console.log('No data available');
                return null;
                // Or throw an error, it's up to you to decide depending on the desired flow of actions
              }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Preamble: Since you tagged your question with the `google-cloud-functions` tag, I make the assumption you are using the the non-modular Admin SDK.*

If I correctly understand your question, the following should do the trick (using the Admin SDK in a Cloud Function):

```
  db.ref('placeID/here:pds:.../-NCe5.../notification')
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        const keyArray = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
        // We pass an Array of Promises to Promise.all(), see the doc (link below)
        return Promise.all(keyArray.map(k => db.ref('/user/' + k + '/notification/' + subMessageID + '/subMessageID/').set(subMessageID)));
      } else {
        console.log('No data available');
        return null;
        // Or throw an error, it's up to you to decide depending on the desired flow of actions
      }
    })
    .then(() => {
       return null;  // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions !!IMPORTANT when writing a CF
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

We use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of the Object returned by snapshot.val() and [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to call several times the asynchronous.

---

The `async`/`await` version would be:

```
  const snapshot = await db.ref('placeID/here:pds:.../-NCe5.../notification').get();
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
        const keyArray = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
        await Promise.all(
        keyArray.map((k) =>
            db
            .ref(
                '/user/' +
                k +
                '/notification/' +
                subMessageID +
                '/subMessageID/'
            )
            .set(subMessageID)
        )
        );
  } else {
        console.log('No data available');
  }
  return null;
```

---

Finally, note that instead of using `Promise.all()` you could use the `update()` method for writing in an atomic manner several nodes to the DB, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) in the doc (see the V8 code version, which corresponds to the non-modular Admin SDK syntax).

Comment: Hello @submariner, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Hello thanks it worked very well. I tried the first part and it works. In the next days I look at the second part. But I have a question in the meanwhile. What if I have to update multiple database entries? Please look at the updated code.

Comment: If you have multiple database entries you can very well pass the corresponding calls to the `set()` method to `Promise.all()`. Actually you could pass an Array of several different Promises to `Promise.all()`; e.g. a write to the Realtime DB, a write to Cloud Storage and a read From a Firestore collection. `Promise.all()` will execute the three calls and return the array of results when done.

Comment: Or you could use the `update()` method for writing in an atomic manner several nodes to the DB as explained in my answer.

Comment: Great thanks. But my code above (suggested code) doesn't work if I want to pass the input K to two paths if I want to set userTime and subMessageID.